# How can I validate TINYMCE Editor with jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, tinymce

I am creating a form and I want to validate my form (including tinymce editor textarea).

This is my code.

```
$('#edit_info').validate({
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'error',
    focusInvalid: false,
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        title: {
            required: true
        },
        logo: {
            required: true
        },
        sort: {
            required: true
        },
        show_on_dashboard: {
            required: true
        },
        description: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

But I have to press 'Submit' 2 times and then the validation occurs. Any idea why?

Comment: Please use search.  This question has been asked a few times before:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tinymce+jquery-validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When TinyMCE is injected into the page the original form element (e.g. `<textarea>`) is no longer visible.  If you use your browser tools you will see that TinyMCE injects a series of `<div>`s and an `<iframe>` effectively hiding your `<textarea>`.

Because of this, if you ask jQuery to look at the value in the `<textarea>` it likely still has its initial value from when you first loaded TinyMCE.

In order to have jQuery validate the underlying `<textarea>` you first have to update the `<textarea>` with the current contents of TinyMCE.  To do this you need to use the `triggerSave()` API.  This will force TinyMCE to immediately update the underlying `<textarea>` with the current value in the editor.